# Angular 2 typescript import to deep directory

Tags: typescript, angular

If i have file structure like this:

- app

  - models

    - model1.ts
    - model2.ts
    - model3.ts
    - index.ts
  - services

    - serviceGroup1
    - serviceGroup1Service1.ts
    - serviceGroup1Service2.ts
    - index.ts
    - serviceGroup2
    - serviceGroup3
    - index.ts

tsconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "mapRoot": "/",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../dist/",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "inlineSources": true
}
```

How to make all model public and import them like this:
serviceGroup1Service1.ts:

```
import * as models from 'models';
```

**Updated file tree**

**Updated files**

Added new barells to system.config.ts

```
'app',
'app/models',
'app/services'
```

Trying to use in serviceGroup1Service1.ts

```
import * from 'app/models'
```

Have an error "Cannot find module 'app/models'

But

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
```

works well. How to do it for my components?

Comment: Thanks for answers. But still have error "[ts] Cannot find module".

Answer (score 1):

Add `app/models.ts`:

```
export * from './models/model1`
export * from './models/model2`
export * from './models/model3`
```

and now you can import them with:

```
import * as models from 'app/models';
```

If you want to use just `models` instead of `app/models` you should add SystemJS map configuration, something like:

```
System.config.map = { models: 'app/models' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer works, but I've noticed the angular2 pattern seems to be "[barrels](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/glossary.html#!#B)" where you would have an index.ts in the models dir that does the "export * from xxx" for each file, then you'd "import * from ./models/".  Both approaches work, just the pattern I've noticed.

There might be some built-in support for generating them (maybe in angular-cli? It generated them when I used it for creating a component), I've only needed a couple and generated them by hand.